# onclick setAttribute workaround for IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, setattribute

I can't seem to get this:

```
top.document.getElementById("clickThis").setAttribute("onclick", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<div style=\"width: 600px; margin: 0 auto .5em;\" class=\"wp-caption alignnone\"><a href=\"<?php echo $full_image_path; ?>\" rel=\"lightbox\" title=\"View in lightbox\"><img class=\"alignnone\" src=\"<?php echo $full_width; ?>\" alt=\"<?php echo $value; ?>\" /></a><p class=\"wp-caption-text\"><?php echo $get_image->caption; ?></p></div>');");
```

To work in IE7, I have tried all of the workarounds I could find online and wondering if anyone could help?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.

Instead, [add an event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) by calling `attachEvent` / `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late, but this was bugging the hell out of me too, and I finally got it.

To get IE to execute dynamically built code during the onclick event, do this:

1. Write the code for all other browsers: element.setAttribute( "onclick", object.varName + "method( " + var + " )" );
2. Use a custom attribute to hold your dynamic statement: element.setAttribute( "exec", object.varName + "method( " + var + " )" );
3. Create an anonymous function to execute the statement stored in our custom attribute when the element is clicked: element.onclick = function(){ eval( this.exec ); };

This approach is working for me in IE9 running in IE7 browser mode, as well as the current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

A couple of things to note:

First, in my case, I needed to execute an objects method. To do that, I need to know the var name for the object, which I set as a property when initiating the class. So the object.varName property is one I created and set in my runtime code.

Second, "exec" is not a standard attribute, which is why it works to hold the string I want to execute. But you can call it what ever you want as long as you use a non-standard attribute.

Third, here's why this works: IE, or at least IE7, will only let you set the onclick event to contain an anonymous function. If you assign an object's method or a variable containing 
a function, the function is executed when the onclick attribute is set instead of when the element is actually clicked. In my case, I couldn't build an anonymous function because the variables change at runtime. So instead, I dynamically build a statement that is then stored in an attribute of the element. The onclick event then executes whatever statement is stored in that attribute.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

worked like a dream when I did this:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") != -1){

    document.getElementById("pb").onclick = function(){ eval( this.onClick ); };
}
```

that way only ie7 looks at it.