# Add onclick to com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement

Tags: image, gwt, onclick

I add an onclic event in a com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement using

imageElement.setAttribute("onclick","var tabla=document.getElementById('tablaWidget');var length=tabla.rows.length; for(var i=0;i

This works in firefox but not in IE.

I read here:  [onclick setAttribute workaround for IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347236/onclick-setattribute-workaround-for-ie7)  that I shouldn't use setAttribute to do this because is not crossbrowser, but I don`t know how to do it because this element doesn´t have the onclick or addEventListener method.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html) instead of [com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/ImageElement.html) for any images that will be used in the UI.  Then you can use [Image#addClickHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#addClickHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler%29) to handle clicks in a cross-browser compatible manner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  The problem is that I need to add this to a com.google.gwt.dom.client.TableCellElement.  And I can`t do it.  What I'm trying to achieve is this:  Getting a table element with Element docTabla = Document.get().getElementById("tablaWidget");  and add images to this table. If I press the image, the row that contains that images is removed.

Comment: If the application was built using GWT, you should refrain from using `getElementById`, and figure out a better design to obtain a reference to the Widget or Composite whose children you wish to modify.

If it's not written with GWT, I still think you should probably use an Image and then use Image's `getElement()` method.

Comment: Im using Vaadin and working in a Widget. This is the code I used, but It doesnt work in any browser: Element t = Document.get().getElementById("tabla");
    TableElement te = (TableElement) t;
    final int rows = te.getRows().getLength() + 1;
    TableRowElement f = te.insertRow(0);
    TableCellElement c = f.insertCell(1);
    Image image = new Image("/P/VAADIN/themes/t/images/d.png");
    image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      getElement().setPropertyString("value", "click");
     }
    });
    c.appendChild(image.getElement());